# Autocompletion in the MySQL command-line client

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, console

In Linux, and many other systems, when navigating the terminal you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto complete a directory or file name.

I'm wondering if there is anything like that in the MySQL terminal. For example, if I want to get the description of `someTableWithRidiculousLongName` I could type `describe someTableW` then <kbd>Tab</kbd> and it would auto-complete the rest.

Does anything like that exist in the MySQL terminal?

Comment: Try mycli, https://github.com/dbcli/mycli

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Edit or create a file called `.my.cnf` in your home directory, containing:

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

Comment: @galarant not necessarily, it better be optional

Comment: @rkmax - It still is optional with the `--disable-auto-rehash` flag. But now you've turned it on by default.

Comment: But, it does not work when I type the commands in small letter.

Answer (score 99):

To enable autocomplete within the MySQL prompt type:

```
mysql> \#
```

After that you can type:

```
mysql> describe someTableW[TAB]
```

To get:

```
mysql> describe someTableWithRidiculousLongName
```

Comment: why that is not the default?

Comment: simple and elegant

Comment: `mysql> rehash`  - As an alternative to "\#", we can also type "rehash" mysql command as follows. Thought of sharing as "rehash" might be easier to remember for some people like me: 

`mysql> rehash` 

After that autocomplete will start working!

Comment: @OussamaElgoumri Because some of us like to paste complex queries into the command line, and these queries might contain tab characters for indentation.

Answer (score 65):

start MySQL console with additional option `--auto-rehash`, i.e.

```
mysql --auto-rehash -u root -p
```

Comment: i dnt know why that does not work for me! the tab is being interpreted as a tab only and does nothing for auto completion.

Comment: @pjp - This feature [does not work on regular Windows builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/autocomplete-in-mysql-under-windows)

Comment: Caution, tabcomplete only works after one is connected to a database as Otheus pointed out in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270309/tab-completion-does-not-work-in-mysql-command-line-client/270616#270616?newreg=334448009e904ef9addb6a9d140cb12e

Answer (score 33):

I know this is an old question, but I've found very helpful MySql cli client with advanced autocompletion:
[mycli](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli). It's much smarter than builtin auto-rehash feature.

Comment: Excellent alternative!

Comment: Oh yea, top notch answer

Comment: `auto-rehash` doesn't work on mine. Switched to mycli and boom.... worked like a pro.

Answer (score 7):

On OS X 10.11.6 I set --auto-rehash as described above, but it did not work.  (This is OS X so mysql is compiled with the BSD *libedit* library.)

Then I remembered that I had set vi key-bindings for mysql client by creating ~/.editrc, containing one line: *bind -v*.  This works great for giving me vi-like navigation in mysql client, but it broke column name completion (I was able to verify this by removing *.editrc*).

So I researched a little bit and found that ~/.editrc should have at least the following lines:

```
bind -v
bind \\t rl_complete
```

With this additional line, name completion works correctly in mysql AND vi-like navigation works also.  (There are other .editrc settings which greatly improve mysql client navigation, but this isn't the place to start that thread of discussion.)

Answer (score 3):

Some notes about auto-rehash:

When you enable autocompletion editing the mysql config file..

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

You can do it for all users or only for one user:

`/etc/my.cnf`: All Users

`~/.my.cnf`: Actual user

You can also disable autocompletion adding:

```
no-auto-rehash
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/08/linux-mysql-autocompletar.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also auto-complete based on the command history. Start typing, then invoke the keys which are bound to `ed-search-prev-history` and `ed-search-next-history`. This applies if mysql comes with libedit support. The default keybindings are Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N, but this can be customized in .editrc. My example for Ctrl-up and Ctrl-down:

```
# start typing, then press Ctrl-Up
bind "\e[1;5A" ed-search-prev-history
# start typing, then press Ctrl-Up, then Ctrl-Down
bind "\e[1;5B" ed-search-next-history
```

Previously, mysql was based on readline, and then `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward` are the correct commands. Configuration then was by means of .inputrc. Same example as above:

```
# these are the key bindings for the readline library
# start typing, then press Ctrl-Up
"\e[1;5A": history-search-backward
# start typing, then press Ctrl-Up, then Ctrl-Down
"\e[1;5B": history-search-forward
```

So, say you started typing `sel` and invoke Ctrl-Up, `select * from some_long_table_name` would come up if that is a command I have used earlier.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is gold to me! Your post is the only explanation I could find as to why my CLI no longer recognised my .inputrc file; as due to change from libreadline to libedit.