# Rehash command in MySQL

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, ubuntu-12.04

What is the command in MySQL to auto-complete the keywords (like the working of tab in Ubuntu Terminal). I use the rehash command, sometimes it works, but sometimes it does not.

Is there any possible alternative for it?

Comment: Looks like this might be answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332338/mysql-console-autocomplete-names)

Comment: Thanks for redirecting, but i have more queries and i am not allowed to comment there :/

Comment: The rehash or auto-rehash, both commands doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut for `REHASH;` is `\#`. Interestingly, I have also discovered on one server (CentOS 6.x, MySQL 5.1) that `REHASH` does not work yet `\#` does.