# How to autocomplete sql command and table name, column in mysql using Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

Using Ubuntu, my `.my.cnf` contains

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```

Suppose, I have a table `provider`;
When I type `describe provi` and <kbd>Tab</kbd> it should autocomplete `describe provider`

`mysql>describe provi`

<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`mysql>describe provider`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete in MySQL under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/autocomplete-in-mysql-under-windows)

Comment: @ostergaard Their solution is `[mysql] auto-rehash` adding in `.my.cnf`. But you saw that I mentioned that I already edited my `.my.cnf` with that. Then why tab completion doesn't work for me?

Comment: are you using Microsoft Windows?

Comment: @ostergaard No, I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: does it work if you type \# at the SQL prompt? (described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096442/1662031)

Comment: @ostergaard This works for table name completion. Don't complete `describe` command from `describ`.

Comment: Which is clearly a different problem/question - agreed?